# Capitalizing each other word using .split and .join functions - Python

Tags: python

```
string = "Hello world, my name is John" 

string = string.split()
string_index = str(string[1::2])
print(string_index.upper())
```

I am trying to use the .split function to pull words from the string.
It works and can pull every other word. For example here "WORLD, NAME, JOHN,"
and now I would like to use the .join function to then put the capitalized words
back into the original string. Creating something like this;
"hello WORLD, my NAME is JOHN".

It has to use the .split and .join functions. I know there are other ways of doing
this.

Below is what I tried and of course failed. I was thinking that it may be joined back into the string somehow.

```
string_index.upper().join(string)
```

I expected it to simply join what I had changed and put it back into the original
string. It did not and wasn't that simple.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach using list slices and assignment to list slices to upcase every other word.

```
>>> string = "Hello world, my name is John"
>>> lst = string.split()
>>> lst[1::2] = [w.upper() for w in lst[1::2]]
>>> ' '.join(lst)
'Hello WORLD, my NAME is JOHN'
>>>
```

Comment: This worked a charm. I was starting to give up. May I ask for a small explanation around

using w.upper() for w in lst. 

What are we checking for?

Comment: Glad it helped. Feel free to accept whichever of these answers has best answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and a ternary expression checking the even/odd words with `%2` (`i%2` evaluates as `1`/`True` if even, else `0`/`False`), then [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
out = ' '.join([s.upper() if i%2 else s for i,s in enumerate(string.split())])
```

Output: `'Hello WORLD, my NAME is JOHN'`

Comment: Alternatively, pass a generator express rather than a list comprehension: `' '.join(s.upper() if i%2 else s for i,s in enumerate(string.split()))`

Comment: @Chris actually no, using a generator in `join` is less efficient than a list comprehension. `join` needs to know the total length before starting to work.

Comment: Fair. I guess I should have put "alternatively" in italics.

Answer (score 0):

- Enumerate over the split input string
- use the index of a word and if it's divisible by 2 make it upper, otherwise take the non modified item
- join them back together with space as the separator.

```py
string = "Hello world, my name is John" 
words = [word.upper() if idx%2==0 else word for idx, word in enumerate(string.split()]
modified_words = ' '.join(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with list comprehension ternary expression:

```
string = "Hello world, my name is John" 

words_list = string.split()

# Capitalize every other word
new_words_list = [word.upper() if i % 2 == 1 else word for i, word in enumerate(words_list)]

# Put the string back together
new_string = " ".join(new_words_list)
```